# how can I update variable inside for loop? The summation inside the loop is not working

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, sum

Good afternoon.

I have tried to update one variable inside the for loop, but it is not working.

What I intended to do was to compute 'r_1 = r + k' then state 'r = r_1'.

In the next loop, I intended to make r_1 in the former loop to r in the current loop, which means updating r variable. But it is not working.

How do I solve this problem?

```
  #Create the lists
  el_r = list()
  
  #Put initial Condition
  r = e_s.iloc[0,1]

  for i in range(len(e_s)-1):

    #Data Sellection
    Q_r1= q_r.iloc[i,1]
    Q_r2= q_r.iloc[i,2]

    #Resetting variables
    
    tide = e_s.iloc[i,1]
    
    #Computation
    k = ( dt * ( Q_r1 + Q_r2 + Q_t(A, tide, r, C1) * n1 + Q_to(A, tide, r, C2) * n2 - Q_g1(H1, W1, tide, r, C3) * n3 - Q_g2(H2, W2, tide, r, C4) * n4 )  / Area(r, c1, c2) )
    
    r_1 =  r+k

    r = r_1


    print(k, r_1)  

    el_r.append((i+1, tide, r))
```

[image]

Comment: That's because you overwrite `r` each time, `r = el_r[i][2]`.  That throws away the previous value.  Ordinarily, I would suggest you move that line out of the loop, but you're reading a new element each time.  I can't guess what you intended.

Comment: It it kind of numerical solution. r(t+1) = r(t) + k(t) is what I intended.

Comment: Is the intent to sum   `el_r[i][2]` and `( dt * ( Q_r1 + Q_r2 + ...)` for all iterations?

Comment: Well, then, do `r = 0` outside of the loop and eliminate the `el_r` list entirely.

Comment: el_r[i][2] = r in the current loop and it is supposed to be put inside the function of Q.
@TimRoberts I will thank you

Comment: My suggestion is:
Start with `r_1 = e_s.iloc[0,1]`, Do `r_1 =  r_1 + k`. For last value add `r_0 = r_1` before update r_1. Remove `r = r_1` (useless). So you have, r_1 as actual value, r_0 as previous value and r and k for calculation.

Comment: `k` is pretty small printing `r+k` to two decimal places won't show you that *change*. ... `r = r_1; print(k, r_1, r)` , You are printing after the assignment - they are the same number.

Comment: @AndréSantos I do not understand what you are saying... Could your put it in coding way?

Comment: @wwii good point! yet it does not chance in time series

Comment: @TimRoberts

I had fixed the code, yet same problem occurs

Comment: How did you fix the code?  Edit the question up above.

Answer (score 0):

The code was working yet, the digits of A is too small to affect the next loop r.
Thus I changed the value of A bigger than before.